# Angular - JSONP injected script did not invoke callback

Tags: angular, jsonp

I am trying to get the status/response when calling a remote url for that I am using the following :

```
  return this.http.jsonp('https://id.atlassian.com/profile/profile.action', 'callback').subscribe(data=>{
   console.log('data ', data)
  }, error=>{
     console.log('error ', error)
  })
```

However I am getting the following error :

> JSONP injected script did not invoke callback

P.S I am using jsonp to bypass CORS errors.

**Live repo** :

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpfpuf

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Angular version 5.2.0

Comment: in stackblitz you are getting different error did you check?

Comment: the same error..

Comment: statusText: "JSONP Error"
url: "https://id.atlassian.com/profile/profile.action?callback=ng_jsonp_callback_0"
__proto__: HttpErrorResponse this is the error you are getting in stackblitz

Comment: @Chellappan stackblitz does not show errors in details, I shared the error I received on the Angular project locally.